# What is Qualcomm Settings (hidden) menu on Moto E?

Tags: settings, motorola, motorola-moto-e

I found a hidden setting menu called Qualcomm Settings on Moto E. How to access the menu (from [IB Times](http://au.ibtimes.com/moto-x-moto-g-moto-e-secret-settings-access-revealed-1420242)):

> 1. Download and install a third-party launcher like *Nova Launcher* from the Play Store.
> 2. Once installed, users can access Nova's menu by pressing longer on the homescreen. It will show a pop-up menu with options like *Nova Actions*, Apps, Shortcuts, Widgets and Wallpapers. Hit *Shortcuts* to access the sub-menu and select *Activities* from list of options that appear.
> 3. On Activities menu, users are required to scroll down until `com.qualcomm.qualcommsettings`. Tap on it to access the hidden *Qualcomm Settings* menu.
> 4. **Android Pit warns the readers to refrain from accessing those settings that they are unaware of**.

Below is the image of the hidden setting menu.

[image: Hidden Menu]

Can anyone tell me what these setting mean?

Comment: FYI, official statement from [Motorola](http://www.androidpit.com/moto-x-and-moto-g-hidden-system-settings-accessible) first: *"The setup menu processor - quoted by the publication - is a tool built on existing devices for testing. So it was not programmed to be easily accessed by the user.To access it and make any changes in the processor configuration menu, the person must have advanced knowledge or follow some instruction disseminated on the Internet. Motorola always recommends that none of these settings are changed as they may affect the normal operation of the appliance."*

Comment: But it's an on-topic question, and it seems I also cannot find relevant info on this menu. Perhaps someone who has experimenting with this could answer though. Edit: [XDA forum has some hints](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-x/general/hidden-qualcomm-settings-moto-x-g-t2838624)

Comment: You can also launch the hidden menu via Tasker. Just hit "show all" in Tasker's Launch App action. Good find!